# Remove unnecessary layers from multi-demensional list python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

My plan is to turn the input of a multidimensional list with an unknown amount of layers i.e. `[["a"], [["b"], ["c"]]]` into `["a", ["b", "c"]]` but currently my output is the same as the original with the below function:

```
def extract(tree):
    for x in range(len(tree)):
        if type(tree[x]) == list:
            extract(tree[x])
        else:
            tree = tree[x]
```

Basically, I want to remove any unnecessary layers in the array that have only one element,

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `tree = tree[x]` doesn't modify the original `tree` object, and thus, your function never modifies it

Comment: Those are not multidimensional arrays, they aren't arrays at all. They are `list` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fixed. Sorry for the wrong teminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a few returns and your code works just fine.

```
def extract(tree):
    for x in range(len(tree)):
        if type(tree[x]) == list:
            tree[x] = extract(tree[x])
        else:
            return tree[x]

    return tree

# test cases
test = [["a"], [["b"], ["c"]]]
print(extract(test))

test = [["a"], [["b"], ["c"], [["b"], ["c"]]]]
print(extract(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
def tree(element):
  if isinstance(element, str):
    return element
  elif len(element) == 1:
    return element[0]

  unfolded = []
  for each in element:
    unfolded.append(tree(each))
  return unfolded

a = [["a"], [["b"], ["c"]]]
print(tree(a)) # => ['a', ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score -1):

1. It's generally good to use isinstance() instead of type() for type checking in code.

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code. Axe319's answer will remove all the inner arrays/lists and return both `[["a"], [["b"], ["c"]]]` and `["a", ["b", "c"]]` as `['a','b','c']`. If you wish to make a list of one, then two, then three etc. (ie. `[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']...`), you'll have to redesign your code.

Comment: No, axe's answer works exactly as expected. Basically, I want to remove any unnecessary layers in the array that have only one element

Comment: Ah I see, yes my mistake adding the returns works like a charm